# Best Practice of creating Sub Domain in MVC.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, subdomain

I should create a website with multiple sub domains(7 projects) which has some common partial views like menu. Each of these projects have different `Data Access Layer` and `Model Layer` in different projects.

**My question**: Is it better to create sub domain for each project in **IIS** or it's better to manage them with a **custom route**?

The biggest problem which I think I will have with custom routing is when modifying where with any modifying on project I should publish whole of the routing project that this cause all web sites stop.

And the main problem with IIS sub domain is with Shared `Partial View`.

So what's the best practice to me?

Answer (score 1):

The custom route option will be less complex.  This is likely your best option (especially for a small team).

We use the sub-domain approach so each website can run and be deployed independently by different teams (we have 30+ developers).  This works but it requires more deployments.  We also had to build an internal Nuget package to share common UI components.